# Stars readjusting themselves in the sky

Tags: star, star-formation

I had a meeting in the evening and thought of grabbing a snack before that. I stepped out of the office along with a colleague. He was on his phone and I was simply staring at the sky wishing it would rain. Although there was no trace of a cloud, however, what I saw was beyond what I expected and could ever imagine.

I saw three stars aligned in an inverted triangle, moving at a decent speed away from each other. For a moment I didn't believe what I was seeing. I quickly called my colleague and asked him if he could see something moving in the sky. Well, we both were astonished as we saw the stars moving away from each other and changing there position in the sky.

After that evening I went back home a was awake till 4 am sitting at the terrace staring at those three stars, wishing them to move again. It's been three days and the stars are still in the same position.

Yes, I can detect those three stars as they were right above the north star.

In these three days, I have done a bunch of research on satellite, shifting stars, supernova and so on but nothing could explain what we saw.

I would love to know if anyone had the same experience as us.

Comment: If they move about, they are not stars. Lights, perhaps. Stars, no. Did you not think to photograph them?

Comment: Just a thought -- I'm no expert, but I wonder if this might have been your brain adjusting its processing of what you saw to your increased focus on that area of the sky. The human eye does not actually zoom in like a camera, but the brain does devote different amounts of effort to processing areas of the visual field that you are interested in, which might make them "seem" bigger to your consciousness.

Comment: Hi Steven, you may be right. However, how would you explain my colleague seeing the same thing?

Comment: @ShreyaPaul I'd have to assume that their brain worked the same way as yours, perhaps aided by a suggestin from you that that was what they might see. I'm guessing though